# REST API access always returns invalid access when requesting client Identifier

Tags: force.com-toolkit-for-net

I am using [the SimpleConsole Sample](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/master/samples/SimpleConsole/Program.cs)

[AppSettings](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/master/samples/SimpleConsole/App.config) I've changed the values to the values of the connected app I am trying to connect to as well as the login information. User,Pass,Token.

I've reset my access token. Created and tried multiple connected apps.

> Line 59: await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret,
>   Username, Password, url);

holds the proper values when I use a breakpoint which it gets from the Appsettings but when passing the values into

> var client = var client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl,
>   auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion); On Line 62

The auth.InstanceUrl and auth.AccessToken are Null so it doesn't authenticate.

Any ideas? Does it work for anyone else?